# Eclipse and internet connection

Tags: android, eclipse

To test apps that use internet connections i need something to configure the quality of it, is there any way to do this in Eclipse?

Thanks.

Comment: You can set connection type in emulator, Add few more details if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-netdelay` parameter with Android emulator to emulate slow internet connections.

See here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options

Comment: Done, it don't alow me until 8 minutes since you respond.

Answer (score 2):

If youre testing in an android emulator you can use the Emulator Control which comes with the android adt. You find it within the DDMS view.